# dojo select set value not working with dynamic generated options

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have dijit.form.select element:

```
<select jsId="selectList" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" ></select>
```

then I use a forEach to populate the options

```
dojo.forEach(someJSONVariable, function(item) {

    selectList.addOption({value: item.id, label: item.name });

    });
```

the default selected element is the first one, but I want to select other option by default so I do:

```
selectList.set("value", "someID");
alert(selectList.get("value");
```

the default selection is always the first element...
but if the option is a fixed option works fine...

is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find set as a function inside of qdijit.form.Selectq. Maybe try:

```
selectList.attr("value", "someID");
```

Although I guess this is the old way...I'm out of date.

Maybe make sure that the select is rendered first? Maybe the default is being set too soon. It may need to go through more of the widget life cycle. I think it should happen after `postCreate`, but you can try after `startup` to be safe.

Comment: All dijit widgets have set now. attr is the old style.

Comment: actually the select is in a contentPane and the "set" is called after the event "onDownloadEnd" so I think the select is rendered. anyway I did "selectList.getOptions()" before the "set" and all the options indeed populated. :S

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is try to hook into the onLoad instead of onDownloadEnd